# Как получить определенную информацию по повторяюшемуся в тексте слову?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Требуется помощь гуру по регулярным выражениям, имеется текст:

```
Техническая информация
Дата
Время 

Документ № 1   

Подпись

Дата 10.08.2020

Какой-то текст

1/10    


Техническая информация
Дата
Время 

Документ № 2

Подпись

Дата 16.09.2020

Снова какой-то текст

2/10

...
```

Подскажите, как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы получить определенную информацию (позиция и номер), слово "Документ" повторяется?

В итоге хочу получить все номера документов и позиции этих документов, т.е. номер документ 1 и позиция 1/10, номер документа 2 и позиция у него 2/10.

Comment: Ответ да возможно это сделать Вас устроит?

Comment: Ищите сначала нужный вам текст потом требуйте // позиция и что там ещё нужно

Comment: `\d+\/\d+(?=\h*\/\/\h*позиция|\h*$)` https://regex101.com/r/7T7kkc/1

Comment: @PotroNik, спасибо за пример. Только "позиция" это комментарий тут для понятности что мне нужно)  Другими словами мне надо получить номер после "Документ №" и позицию, например 1 и 1/10

Comment: @Odyssey, добавьте в вопрос какие данные хотите получить, именно текст из примера который нужен, постараюсь помочь

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7T7kkc/2, попробуйте, проверьте `Документ №\h*(\d)[\S\s]*?(\d+\/\d+)(?:\h*\/\/\h*позиция|\h*$)`

Comment: @PotroNik, спасибо. Я думаю (?:\h*\/\/\h*позиция|\h*$) надо убрать,т.к. "позиция" только здесь комментарий, и номер документ может состоять из нескольких разрядов, значит будет так (\d+). Обновил вопрос^, оказывается между блоками "Документ №" имеется техническая информация, которую не нужно выводить, прошу прощения сразу не заметил ее.

Comment: Такие данные очень редко хранятся именно так, тут явно либо формат какой-то, либо HTML криво спаршеный. Вы уверены, что есть только этот вид данных и никакой другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесу ответ в комментарии:

```
Документ №\h*(\d+)[\S\s]*?(\d+\/\d+)
```

И немного попытаюсь объяснить подробнее
Данным regexp мы ищем совпадения от вхождения **"Документ"** и до **"одна и более цифр/одна и более цифр"**:

---

***Документ № 1

Подпись

Дата 10.08.2020

Какой-то текст

1/10***
Техническая информация
Дата
Время
***Документ № 2

Подпись

Дата 16.09.2020

Снова какой-то текст

2/10***

---

Это полное совпадение которое захватывает регулярное выражение, но, у нас в шаблоне есть группы захвата, данные в круглых скобках `(...)` Их можно получить отдельно.

В первой группе `\1` будет хранится номер документа, во второй группе `\2` будет позиция.
Именно эти группы и нужно использовать далее, так как в `C#` я не силен, то приведу пример со страницы [документации docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netcore-3.1):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"Документ №\h*(\d)[\S\s]*?(?:(\d+\/\d+)|(?=Документ))";
      string input = "Техническая информация
Дата
Время 

Документ № 1   

Подпись

Дата 10.08.2020

Какой-то текст

1/10    


Техническая информация
Дата
Время 

Документ № 2

Подпись

Дата 16.09.2020

Снова какой-то текст

2/10
";
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
      
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("DOC: {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
         Console.WriteLine("POZ: {0}", match.Groups[2].Value);
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
________
// The example displays the following output:
//       DOC:  1
//       POZ:  1/10
//       
//       DOC:  2
//       POZ:  2/10
//
```

О самом регулярном выражении:
`Документ №\h*` - текс Документ № и ноль и более горизонтальных пробельных символов
`(\d+)` - одна и более цифр захватываемых в группу 1
`[\S\s]*?` - ноль и более любых пробельных и не пробельных символов, где `*?` - ленивый квантификатор, который остановится при ближайшем подходящем совпадении
`(\d+\/\d+)` - вторая захватываемая группа, где одна и более цифры указанны через `/` и далее еще одна и более цифра.

---

**С осторожностью!**

В случае если в тексте не будет указана позиция, то выполнение будет проходить до следующего совпадения, т.е. данные шаблон подойдет, если в тексте гарантированно будет для каждого документа указанная позиция.
Если позиция может быть не указана, то следует указать в шаблоне, что бы проверка для данного текста останавливалась при достижении текста "Докумен"

```
Документ №\h*(\d)[\S\s]*?(?:(\d+\/\d+)|(?=Документ))
```

Пример работы: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TS8pzk/1)

Comment: техническую информацию нельзя исключить?

Comment: @Odyssey, можно, используйте группу 1 и 2 которые будут хранить в себе номер договора и позицию соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, думаю: `Документ № (?<number>\d+)\s+(?<signature>[^\n]+)\s*Дата\s*(?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s*(?<text>.*?)\s+(?<position>\d+\/\d+)`. Предполагается, что подпись не содержит переводов строк. Обратите внимание на нежадный захват в тексте.
[Ссылка на тест](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%E2%84%96%20%28%3F%3Cnumber%3E%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Csignature%3E%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%2B%29%5Cs*%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cdate%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%5Cs*%28%3F%3Ctext%3E.*%3F%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cposition%3E%5Cd%2B%5C%2F%5Cd%2B%29&i=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%E2%84%96%201%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%2010.08.2020%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%0D%0A%0D%0A1%2F10%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%E2%84%96%202%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%2016.09.2020%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%0D%0A%0D%0A2%2F10%0D%0A&o=s).

Comment: Сократите ссылку